# carousel for each product(route) ember js

Tags: ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I have a categories route and then product route. Each product has many images.
I want to show this images in carousel. the first product i click i get carousel with images but when i click on second product no carousel is displayed

```
MyApp.ShowCarouselComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    content: [],
    templateName: 'show-carousel',
    classNames: ['carousel', 'slide'],
    init: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        // disable the data api from boostrap
        $(document).off('.carousel.data-api');
        // at least one item must have the active class, so we set the first here, and the class will be added by class binding
        //var cdata = this.get('controller').get('carouselData');
        var obj = this.get('content').get('firstObject');
        Ember.set(obj, 'isActive', true);
        console.log('this is what obj is ');
        console.log(obj);
    },
    previousSlide: function () {
        this.$().carousel('prev');
    },
    nextSlide: function () {
        this.$().carousel('next');
    },
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this.$().carousel();
    },
    willDestroyElement: function () {
        this.$('.carousel').remove();
        this._super();
    },
    indicatorsView: Ember.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: 'ol',
        classNames: ['carousel-indicators'],
        contentBinding: 'parentView.content',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            click: function () {
                var $elem = this.get("parentView.parentView").$();
                $elem.carousel(this.get("contentIndex"));
            },
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(''),
            classNameBindings: ['content.isActive:active']
        })
    }),
    itemsView: Ember.CollectionView.extend({
        classNames: ['carousel-inner'],
        contentBinding: 'parentView.content',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            classNames: ['item'],
            classNameBindings: ['content.isActive:active'],
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('\
                {{view.content}}\
                <img {{bind-attr src="view.content.product_url"}} alt="dfdds"/>\
                <div class="carousel-caption">\
                    <h4>{{view.content}}</h4>\
                    <p>{{view.content.image_description}}</p>\
                </div>')
        })
    })
});
```

show-carousel component

```
  {{view view.indicatorsView}}
  {{view view.itemsView}}
  <a class="left carousel-control" {{action previousSlide target="view"}}>‹</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" {{action nextSlide target="view"}}>›</a>
```

router.js

```
this.resource('categories', {
    path: '/'
}, function () {
    this.resource('category', {
        path: '/:category_id'
    }, function () {
        this.resource('product', {
            path: '/:product_id'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: put your code from init into did insert element

Comment: Thanks you should have put it as answer. I assumed the on route transition the object will get destroyed willDestroyElement() method and reintialization will take place I wonder why this didnt happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Ember views and Ember Components case accessing dom in init() method is a bad idea because it might happen that element that you are trying to access is not yet inserted into dom. so putting code from init method into didInsertElement() might solve your problem.